# When to use asynchronous programming with delegates?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, async-await, task

They seem to be doing the same thing, but I don't know when I'm supposed to use tasks and when normal delegates.

Consider the example below:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    UseDelegates();
    // await UseTasks();
}

private void UseDelegates() {
    Action action = () => {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    };

    var result = action.BeginInvoke(unusedResult => {
        MessageBox.Show("Used delegate.BeginInvoke!");
    }, null);
    action.EndInvoke(result);
}

private async Task UseTasks() {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    });
    MessageBox.Show("Used await with tasks!");
}
```

Comment: I have considered your example... and its a little contrived. what is your real world example?

Comment: When you are forced to use delegates, convert them to tasks, See your prvious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no truly asynchronous work being done in your example. It seems like the only thing you want to do is to offload some synchronous work to a background thread in order to keep the UI thread responsive during the time it takes for the synchronous method - `Thread.Sleep` in this case - to complete.

As [stated on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl); starting with the .NET Framework 4, the Task Parallel Library (TPL) is the preferred way to write multithreaded and parallel code. That's what your `UseTasks()` method does, i.e. it uses `Task.Run` to schedule the call to `Thread.Sleep` on a thread pool thread using the TPL's default task scheduler.

The BeginInvoke/EndInvoke pattern is known as the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm). This pattern is no longer recommended for new development as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/).

So to answer your questions, you are generally "supposed to use tasks" when offloading work to a background thread in .NET 4+ applications.

Comment: If I remove this `action.EndInvoke(result);` then the UI won't freeze... I added that just for completeness.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously says that delegates are "*a good technique to use with file or network operations.*" and now I'm confused... I know the tasks are newer so I guess I'm supposed to use them instead of delegates.

Comment: File and network operations should be asynchronous and the APIs should be awaitable using async/await. All new APIs are.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have given. I would use `Task` every time. The library and syntax has been created with the very aim of getting rid of `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` type patterns.

The only time you probably don't want to use `Task` over an older library is in desktop apps that use `BackgroundWorker`, which is specifically for running long running background work, that wants to report progress easily to the UI thread. This sort of things isn't as elegant with tasks.